# cant save previous menuitem state

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi In my app I add a menuitem on the action bar called "add to favorite" shown by white star icon. When user click it this icon become disappear and other yellow star comes up...this works fine..but the problem is that when I switch to another activity or when I restart my app again I see that white favorite star icon and the previous event has been lost. How can I save this state. I tried saveInstanceState but of no use..
 Here my code.

```
On PrepareOptionMenu (Menu menu){
If (favClicked){
menu.finditem (R.id.id_favorite).setvisible (false);
menu.finditem (R.id.id_favorite 2). setvisible (true);
}
else if (! favClicked){
menu.finditem ( R.id.id_favorite).setvisible (true);
menu.finditem (R.id.id_favorite 2).setvisible (false);
}
return super . onPrepareOptionMenu (menu);
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle saveInstanceState){
super.onRestoreInstanceState (saveInstanceState);
favClicked=saveInstanceState. getBoolean ("favClicked")
}
```

AND THEN I USE THE  RESTOREINSTACESTATE METHOD SAME LIKE THE SAVEINSTANCE STATE...BUT IT DOSENT WORK FOR ME.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store somewhere (database or your method of choice) what you have already favorite.

Once that procedure is created, on your onStart() and when you show another item, check if the current item is favorited or not and set your menuItem accordingly.

I don't think saving the instance state has any use in this scenario.

Comment: So how can I take start with database save..I am using dbadapter for storing list of favorites...how can I store menuitem clicked event in database??

Comment: You don't have to store menuitems, you have to query the db to see if the subject is in the favorite list...

Comment: Can you please provide me the code what should I do in my dbadapter? I want that when I change my visibility to hide of one menuitem and show other through activity then it remains or save the visibility option. But after restart the app or change the orientation of app the visibility again comes to the initial state and not saved as I want. I want to save the visibility option thats all what I want.